# Bind collection of lines to canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, drawing, shapes

I have an observable collection of line segments specified by its boundary points. How can I bind it to draw the lines on a canvas?

I have seen the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030191/2336304) for shapes using only one point to define the position. But for applying this approach to lines it need awkward precomputations on coordinates to get the position of outer rectangle and make line coordinates relative to it. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: could you share what you have tried along with the strategy for precomputations on coordinates  the  so we can have a look.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426460/bind-an-observablecollection-to-lines)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example how you could do it:

The line is defined as follows:

```
public class Line
{
    public Point From { get; set; }

    public Point To { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                      X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                      Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="3"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Lines = new ObservableCollection<Line>
        {
            new Line { From = new Point(100, 20), To = new Point(180, 180) },
            new Line { From = new Point(180, 180), To = new Point(20, 180) },
            new Line { From = new Point(20, 180), To = new Point(100, 20) },
            new Line { From = new Point(20, 50), To = new Point(180, 150) }
        };

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the lines are static, i.e. if you update the `From` and `To` positions, the UI will not update. If you want the UI to update, you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `Line` class.

This sample shows a window that looks like this:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It works! But how is it possible if ItemsControl wraps each ItemTemplat'ed object into its own [container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1640166/2336304)? Why so linked answers need those workarounds?

Comment: I think the key point is that all containers have `Canvas.Top=0` and `Canvas.Left=0`, i.e. they are aligned to the same origin.

Comment: Possible it's specific only for line since it requires to specify X and Y (inside it as element) instead of shifts the whole object from parent boundaries because only canvas allows absolute positioning of child content and it would be impossible inside ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, what I often do to avoid the *ItemsControl* is to use PolyLine and simply bind a collection of points. In the XAML:

```
 <Polyline Points="{Binding Points}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness=".1" />
```

Your code would simply be a PointCollection:

```
namespace YourNameSpace.ViewModels
{
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    #region Parameters
    private PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
    public PointCollection Points
    {
        get { return points; }
        set
        {
            points = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Points");
        }
    }

   public MainViewModel()
    {


        PointCollection polygonPoints = new PointCollection
        {
             new Point(10, 50),
             new Point(100, 50),
             new Point(50, 30),
             new Point(75, 100),
             new Point(75, 10)
        };

        this.Points = polygonPoints;
    }
  }}
```

I find the ItemsControl will not work in some instances. Perhaps a defect in the WPF or something I don't understand. It is certainly more complicated than simple binds which can achieve the same results.

One thing to keep in mind is that you can't just add points to the already bound control and perform a NotifyPropertyChanged and expect it to work. You have to actually set an entirely new PointCollection. You can copy the old PointCollection to the new one via a constructor so it isn't much of a hassle.

Comment: Now I'm already not in context of this problem (didn't use WPF >3 years) and cannot evaluate your solution but hope it will be usefull for others.